# HTML form not submitting values

Tags: php, html, forms

This is my form and it is not passing any values.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
 <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .welcome {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                background-color:red;
                font-weight:bold;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitimg(myvalue)
            {
                document.getElementById('type').value = myvalue;
                document.getElementById('survey').submit(); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="height: 232px; width: 500px">
            <form action="" method="post" name="survey" id="survey">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="welcome"><br>Welcome!</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div id="question1" style="display: inline;">
                                <h3>
                                    Are You 30+ Years Old?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px">     </div>
                                <input type="button" name="age30" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';">
                                <input type="button" name="age30" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';">
                            </div>
                            <div id="question2" style="display: none;">
                                <h3>
                                    Are You Looking for a Date?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px">     </div>
                                <input type="button" name="date" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';">
                                <input type="button" name="date" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';">
                            </div>
                            <div id="question3" style="display: none;">
                                <h3>
                                    Which Girl Is Your Type?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px">     </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="">
                                <img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="submitimg('type1');">
                                <img src="http://jenntgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="submitimg('type2');">
                                <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Q_owQUxNjdQ/Te3ALCmT3oI/AAAAAAAAAnk/wv9r0b0MT-g/s1600/600px-MA_Route_3.svg_.jpg" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="submitimg('type3');">
                                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wY_qFr2pcAs/UCxhAayJ6oI/AAAAAAAAC6w/PgtLs2O_4g8/s1600/4.png" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="submitimg('type4');">
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    <?php
        $age30 = $_POST['age30'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        echo $_POST['age30'];
    ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why do your buttons have same names? It may be the issue.

Comment: please edit code tag in your question

Comment: I don't understand this guy i've edited this question twice and he still puts the wrong formatting..

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your html. Names should be unique. In your case it's better to use radio than button.

```
<input type="radio" name="age30" value="yes">
<input type="radio" name="age30" value="No" >


echo $_POST['age30'];
```

Test this code.

Also change your submiting function to this(Jquery Example)

```
  $(function(){
            $(".submit_img").click(function (){
               $("#survey").submit(); // this line will submit form
            });
   });
```

now when you add to element 'submit_img' class, then if someone click this element the form with id=survey will be submitted.

```
<img src="http://jenntgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;" class="submit_img">
```

**[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9ku-sjd)**

Comment: When I click on the image for the last question, nothing happens.

Comment: @DavidJahn do you have item that has id="type"? what do you need this function for? I don't find any logic in this.

Comment: based on what picture is selected, i want to be able to for example search mysql database for the type selected. All I want is for this form to submit and come back with the variables that I set the $_POST to in the php. It doesn't seem to be submitting.

Comment: I fixed that and added the id="type" to every image that I have. the form still is not submitting

Comment: @DavidJahn to use jquery you should include script <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Morover ID is unique! Use class to multiple elements. Check my code. ".submit_img" refers to elements with class="submit_img". #survey refers to element with id="survey"

Comment: What the person above suggested is not exactly what I want. I want the image to submit the form as well as submit the value that the image is set to.

Comment: I've created fiddle check it and fit it to your needs http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9ku-sjd

Comment: I have posted the webpage online so that you can see what I have done so far. http://davidjahn.info/DavidJahnNet/form.php

Comment: With jquery it is more simple ;) just usage of `.next();` In your example you don't save the results of survey it's just pure JS.

Comment: how would I use .next(); where would I put it

Comment: I have reuploaded the file to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try rename inputs like this

```
<input type="button" name="date[]" value="Yes">
<input type="button" name="date[]" value="No">
```

Answer (score -1):

Please specify an action for your form. Create another php file to get the POST variables and put that name inside action.

Comment: action is not required in if it is not specified then action is the same page where submit was invoked.